# CSS - How to center an image without class or id?

Tags: css

I have the following code:

```
<footer>
    <p>
        Some text ...
    </p>
    <p>
       <img ...>
    </p>
</footer>
```

I can center all `<p>` content by using the code:

```
footer p {
    text-align: center;
}
```

But how i can center only the image? 
Note: i can't change the html code.

Comment: Is the image the only thing in the paragraph?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the image `display:block` and use `margin:auto` to center it.

```
footer p img {
        display: block;
        margin: auto;

    }
```

```css
footer p img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod veniam, ducimus enim distinctio porro officia eius voluptatem temporibus. Ea voluptas nesciunt doloremque facilis autem, unde quisquam doloribus ipsum et. Quas et temporibus fuga sunt odit
    hic enim voluptate ratione numquam ab, quibusdam inventore. Eligendi blanditiis, labore pariatur quisquam voluptas perspiciatis.
  </p>
  <p>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-150-150-10.jpg" alt="">
  </p>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
footer p:nth-child(2) {
 text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: May not be the preferred method, but it is an option. Not sure why you got downvoted: http://jsfiddle.net/4yxgbu74/